# Rotate player to face objective java slick

Tags: java, rotation, trigonometry, slick2d

So I am currently working on learning slick. I was doing fine until I ran into a problem. I have been trying to find a answer for a good hour and could not. So I decided to post it on here.

My Problem: I have player on a 800 X 800 Grid. I am trying to make the player move to a certain point on the grid in a straight line. Now I can make him move on the X then turn and move on the Y, But I want to make him get there as fast as possible. So I figured if I could make a right triangle from the following points (Player pos, Target Pos, and the X,Y intercept see my image bellow).

```
My code:
Adj = (int) (TargetX-x); // Get The size of the Adjacent leg.
Opp =   (int) (TargetY-y); // Get the size of the Opposite leg.
OppAdj = Opp/Adj;          //Inverse tan is Opposite/Adjacent
TargetAngle =  Math.abs(Math.atan(Opp/Adj)*100);  //Keep the angle positive, and use inverse tan to get the missing angle.
```

Now what I thought this would do, is solve for the missing angle so I could rotate the player by that amount so the player can move in a straight line and hit the objective.

What this ends up doing though is is giving me a target angle of 73 degrees and a the Variable OppAdj ends up being 1.0.

What is wrong with my code?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Oops Can't post a image because of my reputation!

Comment: That's ok, I think my answer will solve your problem

Comment: @Pick It didn't work But I think, I know what I am doing wrong, finding the missing angle wont tell me how much my player needs to rotate, I got to find some way to make my player rotate so it is on the hypotenuse of the triangle. Would you be willing to help me figure out how to do this? I will accept your answer either way.

Comment: I'll help you later; I am busy now. I'll comment on this question when I am ready

Comment: Alright, come to this gallery chat room when ready: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20535/picklishdoorknob-imnotloved-chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OppAdj = Opp/Adj;
```

That is the problem. You should do this:

```
OppAdj = (double)(Opp)/Adj;
```

That way it will give you a `double` for accuracy. By the way:

```
TargetAngle =  Math.abs(Math.atan(Opp/Adj)*100);
```

Should be:

```
TargetAngle =  Math.abs(Math.atan(OppAdj)*100);
```